# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `[xxx.Class;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

Tags: java, spring-boot

`I have a problem that I want to consume data from an api but when I connect to it it returns this error: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type` [xxx.Class;`from Object value (token`JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
This method is what I am using to connect to the api.
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Comment: Its an error thrown when the JSON is malformed.

Comment: Please post code as text and not an image of the debugger (which might contain sensitive data). Moreover, it is always better to post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Just to clarify; the expected result is what you are receiving from the server, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to deserialize a `Posiciones` array, but you are receiving an object which contains an array of `Posiciones`s. So you are expecting `[{"chapa": "abc", ...}, {"chapa": "efg", ...}, ...]` but receiving `{"posiciones": [{"chapa": "abc", ...}, {"chapa": "efg", ...}, ...]}`. If it is the case, just wrap the array in an object:

```
public class PosicionesResponse {

  private Posiciones[] posiciones;

  //constructors, getters, setters

}
```

Then you can perform the request this way:

```
ResponseEntity<PosicionesResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, PosicionesResponse.class);
```